# Is there any way to find the position of a variable in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For example in

```
      {colour: 'red',x:0,y:20},
      {colour: 'orange',x:0,y:40},
      {colour: 'yellow',x:0,y:60},
      {colour: 'green',x:0,y:80},
      {colour: 'blue',x:0,y:90},
      {colour: 'purple',x:0,y:100},
      {colour: 'pink',x:0,y:120},
      {colour: 'brown',x:0,y:140},
      {colour: 'white',x:0,y:160},
      ]
```

Red is 0, orange is 1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
var arr = [{colour: 'red',x:0,y:20},
      {colour: 'orange',x:0,y:40},
      {colour: 'yellow',x:0,y:60},
      {colour: 'green',x:0,y:80},
      {colour: 'blue',x:0,y:90},
      {colour: 'purple',x:0,y:100},
      {colour: 'pink',x:0,y:120},
      {colour: 'brown',x:0,y:140},
      {colour: 'white',x:0,y:160},
      ];
      
var position = arr.findIndex(a=>a.colour == 'orange');
console.log(position);
```